# Make Multiple Calls to One API With List of IDs

Tags: python, list, api, loops, rest

I have a list of airports I would like to get flight information for from an API. The API only allows users to search one airport as a time. I tried to create a loop that would iterate over the list of airports but it was unsuccessful. I have 5,000 airports I need to pass to the API. Below I give a sample list of airports for example purposes.

```
apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
apiUrl = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx/' 
auth_header = {'x-apikey':apiKey}

airports = [['HLZN'], ['HLLQ'],['HLLB'],['HLGT'],['HLMS'],['HLLS'],['HLTQ'],['HLLT'],['HLLM']] 

payload = {'max_pages': 1}

#Create an empty list to hold responses
json_responses = []

#Iterate through list
for airport in airports:
    response = requests.get(apiUrl + f"airports/{airports}/flights",params=payload,
               headers=auth_header)
    if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json())
    else:
    print("Error executing request")
    results = response.json
    #This presumes the JSON response is a dict, if the response is a list, use extend instead of
        append
    json_responses.append(response.json())

#Create a DataFrame from a list containing all of the gathered responses.
all_acct_df = pd.DataFrame(json_responses)
```

The error I get is : "Error Parsing Arguments Parsing_ERROR Invalid argument ID supplied 400"

I tried passing one airport ID through this looping code and it goes through but it's not iterating over lists.

I'm new to looping and API's so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `{airports}` should be `{airport[0]}`. You're putting the entire list into the URL, not the current element of the iteration.

Comment: Why is each airport in a nested list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "The API only allows users to search one airport as a time" then you may have to call it multiple times without hacks.
But you may want to consider a ProcessPoolExecutor or task queue manager like Celery.

```
responses = []

def get_response(airport):
    # call the API and storge the data
    res = requests.get(url)
    responses.appnd(res.json())

for airport in airports:
    ap = airport[0] # as your data
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_work=50) as executor:
    executor.submit(call, ap)
```

Comment: Thank you Mas Zero and Barmar. Both of your answers worked!